# How to find nearest match from current context node

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I've got a rather large XML file that I'm trying to parse using a C# application and the HtmlAgilityPack. The XML looks something like this:

```
...
<tr>
<td><b>ABC-123</b></td>
<td>15</td>
<td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>AB-4-320</td>
<td>11</td>
<td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>ABC-123</b></td>
<td>15</td>
<td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>AB-4-320</td>
<td>11</td>
<td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>CONTROLLER1</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
<td>CONTROLLER2</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
...
```

Basically a series of table rows and columns that repeats. I'm first doing a search for a controller by using:

```
string xPath = @"//tr/td[starts-with(.,'CONTROLLER2')]";
HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xPath);
foreach (HtmlNode link in nodes) { ... }
```

Which returns the correct node. Now I want to search backwards (up) for the first (nearest) matching `<td>` node that starts with text "ABC":

```
string xPath = @link.XPath + @"/parent::tr/preceding-sibling::tr/td[starts-with(.,'ABC-')]";
```

This returns all matching nodes, not just the nearest one. When I attempted to add [1] to the end of this XPath string, it didn't seem to work and I've found no examples showing a predicate being used with an axes function like this. Or, more likely, I'm doing it wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know the correct syntax with HtmlAgilityPack, but assuming the context node is the CONTROLLER2 td in your first step, then you should try `(./parent::tr/preceding-sibling::tr/td[starts-with(.,'ABC-')])[1]`, i.e. with englobing parenthesis to consider a node-set of matching nodes, and then selecting the 1st one

Comment: @pault. Tried that, but it's returning all the preceding matches in the file instead of just the nearest one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this XPath :

```
/parent::tr/preceding-sibling::tr[td[starts-with(.,'ABC-')]][1]/td[starts-with(.,'ABC-')]
```

That will search for nearest preceding `<tr>` that has child `<td>` starts with 'ABC-'. Then get that particular `<td>` element.

There are at least two approaches you can pick when using HtmlAgilityPack :

```
foreach (HtmlNode link in nodes)
{
    //approach 1 : notice dot(.) at the beginning of the XPath
    string xPath1 = 
        @"./parent::tr/preceding-sibling::tr[td[starts-with(.,'ABC-')]][1]/td[starts-with(.,'ABC-')]";
    var n1 = node.SelectSingleNode(xPath1);
    Console.WriteLine(n1.InnerHtml);

    //approach 2 : appending to XPath of current link
    string xPath2 = 
        @"/parent::tr/preceding-sibling::tr[td[starts-with(.,'ABC-')]][1]/td[starts-with(.,'ABC-')]";
    var n2 = node.SelectSingleNode(link.XPath + xPath2);
    Console.WriteLine(n2.InnerHtml);
}
```

Comment: I tested this using sample XML from OP and HAP, works fine *as far as I can see*. So, explanation of what's wrong with this answer would be great.

Comment: yep, no hard feelings if downvoter has a valid reason to downvote this. The problem is, no explanation and I can't see any obvious reason so far.

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to use LINQ-to-XML instead of the HAP then this works:

```
var node = xml.Root.Elements("tr")
    .TakeWhile(tr => !tr.Elements("td")
        .Any(td => td.Value.StartsWith("CONTROLLER2")))
    .SelectMany(tr => tr.Elements("td"))
    .Where(td => td.Value.StartsWith("ABC-"))
    .Last();
```

I got this result:

```
<td>
  <b>ABC-123</b>
</td>
```

(Which I checked was the second matching node in your sample, not the first.)

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question. Unfortunately, HTML is rarely XML compliant (and XHTML never broke through...).

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
//tr/td[starts-with(.,'CONTROLLER2')]/(parent::tr/preceding-sibling::tr/td[starts-with(normalize-space(.),'ABC-')])[1]
```

since the target node contains unwanted spaces, the use of `normalize-space` is a must.

Comment: Where do you see a space?

Comment: apparently, the space is only in my test file, since I pretty printed it. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I think an XPATH like this (from the current CONTROLLER2 node) should do it:

```
string xPath = "../preceding-sibling::tr[starts-with(td , 'ABC-')][1]/td[starts-with(. , 'ABC-')]";
```

It means

- get back once ancestor level up (..)
- from there, select all preceding sibling TR elements that have TD elements that start with 'ABC-'
- get the first (reverse order) of these TR.
- from this TR element, get TD elements that starts with 'ABC-'

Comment: That appears to return the last match in the entire file, not the nearest.

Comment: Ok, I think I see what you mean. Your sample doesn't exhibit the fact you have ABC nodes *after* the controller node, but you do have that situation. Is that correct?